# Add AWS tags automatically to all services - Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I wrote an ansible playbook that creates a vpc. I noticed that there are other services created automatically like DHCP, RT ect.
The problem is, that the resource tag I add to the VPC are not added to the other services.
Is there a way that the tags will be added automatically while creating the VPC?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create the tag for every service at the time of creation or later. you can add tagging using ansible playbook like ec2 tags module:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/ec2_tag_module.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So there is no way to get them taged automatically.

By adding the link, you mean this:
`- name: Ensure all volumes are tagged
   ec2_tag:
    region:  eu-west-1
    resource: '{{ item.id }}'
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: dbserver
      Env: production
  with_items: '{{ ec2_vol.volumes }}`

Another problem:
Once I create the VPC a RT is created with it but I don't have its ID so I cant add my tags.